# OpenStreetMap for flutter

Tags: flutter, dictionary, dart, openstreetmap

I want to use OSM in flutter .but I cannot add it to flutter and i want to use any free maps like this.
I don't wanna pay for APIs .what should I do?
Is there any way to add OSM To flutter.
it takes couples of day and I can't add any map to my app!

Comment: Have a look at [Flutter Map](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_map)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the [`flutter_map`](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_map) package, like quoci said in the comments.

It allows you to view maps from any source that gives a URL as an access method. There are plenty of setup instructions and examples on the package's readme page for you to get started.

Comment: thank you quoci and JaffaKetchup.that was Great! and I got what I want!